# ¿cómo recorrer una matriz con una ventana n*n o n*m;?

Tags: c++, matlab

Tengo una imagen nxn y quiero recorrerla de 1 en uno con una ventana o mascara de nxn o nxm.en mi caso una matriz de 200x200 con una vetana de 9x9.

Comment: Hola, JGDiaz. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu comentario y añadir lo que has intentado hasta ahora? De esta forma podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, ¿podrías compartir lo que has intentado y especificar si trabajas con C++ o Matlab? No entiendo el motivo por el que has puesto las dos etiquetas.

Comment: Es en Matlab, lo que debe hacer es recorrer la matriz de uno en uno, en recortes de 9*9 y guardar cada recorte en una variable en total debo obteber 36481 recortes. ya que mi imagen es 200 por 200 i,j llega a 191. Posteriormente se vectoriza.

`B = imread('R.png');
B1 = rgb2gray(B);
B1 = double(B1);
[f,c]=size(B1);

for i=1:f-9
    for j=1:c-9
         v=B1(1:9,1:9);
    end
end`

Comment: Eso que colocas en el comentario debes colocarlo en la pregunta. Para ello puedes hacer clic en [edit] y así podrás añadir más detalles a  tu pregunta. Saludos